# SELinux: How to show all allowed rules for a type?

Tags: redhat, selinux

For an arbitrary object type, e.g. `user_tmp_t`, I want to know which processes are allowed to access this tag. How do I find all allow rules that reference `user_tmp_t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *directly* find the processes that can transition to a given type, but you can sort of do it indirectly.

It's time to get familiar with the `sesearch` tool. This tool lets you query the SELinux policy in a variety of ways.

Here, we will see which types can transition to the `user_tmp_t` type. Among them will be types for the processes you are interested in. As you can see, this also gives you some hints as to *what* the process will be allowed to do.

```
# sesearch -T -t user_tmp_t
Found 44 semantic te rules:
   type_transition staff_sudo_t user_tmp_t : process staff_t; 
   type_transition auditadm_sudo_t user_tmp_t : process auditadm_t; 
   type_transition thumb_t user_tmp_t : file thumb_tmp_t; 
   type_transition thumb_t user_tmp_t : dir thumb_tmp_t; 
   type_transition thumb_t user_tmp_t : sock_file thumb_tmp_t; 
   type_transition mozilla_plugin_t user_tmp_t : file mozilla_plugin_tmp_t; 
   type_transition telepathy_msn_t user_tmp_t : file telepathy_msn_tmp_t; 
   type_transition mozilla_plugin_t user_tmp_t : dir mozilla_plugin_tmp_t; 
   type_transition telepathy_msn_t user_tmp_t : dir telepathy_msn_tmp_t; 
   type_transition mozilla_plugin_t user_tmp_t : sock_file mozilla_plugin_tmp_t; 
   type_transition telepathy_msn_t user_tmp_t : sock_file telepathy_msn_tmp_t; 
   type_transition mozilla_plugin_t user_tmp_t : fifo_file mozilla_plugin_tmp_t; 
   type_transition alsa_t user_tmp_t : file alsa_tmp_t; 
   type_transition staff_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : dir gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition user_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : dir gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition alsa_t user_tmp_t : dir alsa_tmp_t; 
   type_transition staff_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : sock_file gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition user_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : sock_file gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition dbadm_sudo_t user_tmp_t : process dbadm_t; 
   type_transition secadm_sudo_t user_tmp_t : process secadm_t; 
   type_transition gpg_pinentry_t user_tmp_t : sock_file gpg_pinentry_tmp_t; 
   type_transition mozilla_plugin_config_t user_tmp_t : file mozilla_plugin_tmp_t; 
   type_transition mozilla_plugin_config_t user_tmp_t : dir mozilla_plugin_tmp_t; 
   type_transition sysadm_sudo_t user_tmp_t : process sysadm_t; 
   type_transition virt_qemu_ga_unconfined_t user_tmp_t : file svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition svirt_t user_tmp_t : file svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition virt_qemu_ga_unconfined_t user_tmp_t : dir svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition secadm_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : dir gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition httpd_t user_tmp_t : dir httpd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition svirt_t user_tmp_t : dir svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition virt_qemu_ga_unconfined_t user_tmp_t : lnk_file svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition svirt_t user_tmp_t : lnk_file svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition secadm_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : sock_file gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition svirt_tcg_t user_tmp_t : file svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition svirt_tcg_t user_tmp_t : dir svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition auditadm_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : dir gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition xguest_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : dir gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition svirt_tcg_t user_tmp_t : lnk_file svirt_tmp_t; 
   type_transition auditadm_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : sock_file gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition xguest_gkeyringd_t user_tmp_t : sock_file gkeyringd_tmp_t; 
   type_transition chrome_sandbox_t user_tmp_t : file chrome_sandbox_tmp_t; 
   type_transition chrome_sandbox_t user_tmp_t : dir chrome_sandbox_tmp_t; 
   type_transition gconfd_t user_tmp_t : file gconf_tmp_t; 
   type_transition gconfd_t user_tmp_t : dir gconf_tmp_t; 

Found 298 named file transition filename_trans:
----(omitted)----
```